Can I use wifi and ethernet at the same time?
I am planning to build an AirPlay receiver with Ubuntu.
The network configuration in my house is a bit complicated. My home network is in a "Double NAT" state, so other smartphones inside the NAT cannot use Bonjour to find the Ubuntu server on the outside. However, my server is also used as a file server, so it needs to be wired to the internet on the outside to improve speed.
Is it possible for the server to use WiFi for communication on certain ports and wired ethernet for all other communication?

Yes, on a Linux Ubuntu system, you can use both WiFi and Ethernet (wired) connections simultaneously, each with different IP addresses.
Linux automatically handles routing for multiple interfaces, but you might want specific traffic to go through a specific interface. You can configure the routing rules with the ip route command to specify which interface to use for particular destinations.

Yes. Just plug in your Ethernet and turn on WiFi in settings and it should work without any problems.
If you want to use WiFi and Ethernet for different traffic, you can set specific routing using ip route. I think you can change it by using network manager.
